# How to enable fingerprint sensor in Dell G7 Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS?

Tags: drivers, 20.04, dell, ubuntu-drivers, fingerprint-reader

I am trying to install the driver for my fingerprint sensor.
But I have not found any drivers yet.

From hw-probe I found

> usb:27c6-530c;ff-00-00;failed;fingerprint reader;;Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd.;Fingerprint Reader;Goodix

Can anyone suggest any possible fixes for this?

Comment: Check with Dell.